# How to set password policy for specific user or group in RHEL using PAM configuration

Tags: linux, rhel, pam

How to set password policy for specific user or group in RHEL using PAM configuration?

I changed my "/etc/pam.d/system-auth" file as below but still I am not able to set easy

```
password for user "dkumar" with group "dkumar"
password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup dkumar
password sufficient pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 minlen=1
password sufficient pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password required pam_deny.so
```

Comment: Instead of describing just what you've done, please tell us what you'd like to accomplish in the end. Are you trying to restrict access to your system for just one user? If that's the case, use pam_access.so instead of what you propose. By the way, in Unix & Linux or Super User your question might get more attention.

Comment: Thank you for your response ,I just want to set user(or group) level password policy. My requirement is to allow only one user to set his  password whatever he want, without checking the default password policy.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use FreeIPA. It's very flexible and will match to your demands.